# Select from row to last row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-limit

Is it possible for me with MySQL to select the from a specific row to the end of the table, without knowing how many rows there are left?

My query at the moment is:

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid='$fid' ORDER BY up_id DESC
```

But I want to be able to something like:

```
SELECT * FROM updates WHERE userid='$fid' ORDER BY up_id DESC LIMIT '$myRow' to EndOfTable
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a large value like 999999999 that is going to be bigger than the table.  So:

```
limit $myRow, 999999999
```

Although less popular, I prefer the syntax:

```
limit 999999999 offset $myrow
```

Comment: @Colum . . . `limit` is applied after all the real work for the query has been done.  It *will* slow down your code, but only because a larger volume of data needs to be processed (which is what you should be expecting).

Comment: Its the best approach to my problem so it will have to do